# Creating a Community User from LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, customer-community, customer-portal

I am trying to create a community User using LWC. But the method Site.CreatePortalUser returns null when I run the command via anonymous console and my LWC catches an error user already logged in (which is not possible because I am using unique username/email everytime with apex returning nothing if I run it using LWC. Also I read that I can try using forceSSL=true but I am not sure how to do that in LWC. Here is my controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String registerUser(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String email, String communityNickname, String password){
    try {
        System.debug('in register user');
        Set<String> communityNicknameSet = new Set<String>();
        for(User usr : [Select Id, CommunityNickname From User Where CommunityNickname != null]){
            communityNicknameSet.add(usr.CommunityNickname);
        }
        
        String uniqueCommunityNickName;

        if(communityNicknameSet.isEmpty()){
            if(communityNickname.length() > 4){
                uniqueCommunityNickName = communityNickname.substring(0, 4) + String.valueOf( Integer.valueOf(Math.random() * 10000) );    
            } else {
                uniqueCommunityNickName = communityNickname + String.valueOf( Integer.valueOf(Math.random() * 10000) );
            }         
        } else {
            for(Integer i=1; i <= 9999 ; i++){
                if(communityNickname.length() > 4){                      
                    uniqueCommunityNickName = communityNickname.substring(0, 4) + String.valueOf( Integer.valueOf(Math.random() * 10000) );                    
                } else {
                    uniqueCommunityNickName = communityNickname + String.valueOf( Integer.valueOf(Math.random() * 10000) );
                }
                if(!communityNicknameSet.contains(uniqueCommunityNickName)){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.debug('communityNicknameSet '+communityNicknameSet);
        
        User u = new User();
        u.firstName = firstName;
        u.lastName = lastName;
        u.Username = username;
        u.Email = email;
        u.CommunityNickname = 'myCommunityTest';  
        String accountId;

   /*     Account portalAccount = new Account();
        portalAccount.Name = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
        insert portalAccount;

        portalAccount.IsPartner = true;
        update portalAccount;
        System.debug('portalAccount '+portalAccount); */
        
   //     accountId = portalAccount.Id;
        accountId = '0011D000017DzNV';
        System.debug('user id '+u +' '+ accountId+' '+ password+' '+false);
        System.debug('user id '+Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password));
        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);
        System.debug('user id '+Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password));
        if (userId != null) {         
         //   String emailResult = sendWelcomeMail(u, userId);
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                ApexPages.PageReference pageRef = Site.login(username, password, null);
                if(pageRef != null) return pageRef.getUrl();
            }
            else {
                ApexPages.PageReference page = System.Page.SiteRegisterConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page.getUrl();
            }
        }
        return null;
     //   throw new CalloutException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        system.debug('e.getMessage+   '+e.getMessage());           
  //      if(!Test.isRunningTest()) throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

my LWC

```
registerUser({ firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, username: this.userName, email: this.email, communityNickname: this.firstName, password: this.password,
                })
                    .then((result) => {
                        if(result){
                            console.log('result ', result);
                            window.location.href = result;
                        }
                        this.showTermsAndConditionsLoading = false;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        this.error = error;
                        console.log('error-',error);
```

Comment: Are you running this as a Site User? The registration works as a Site Guest User.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava not sure what means by site user, I am trying to just register regular first time user on communities. I thought this might work

Comment: What I mean is you are unauthenticated before running registration? When you run the logic within developer console it should not work.

Comment: If I try to register in incognito, it is still not working @MohithShrivastava